# BitSet bug in cracking the coding interview?

Tags: algorithm, bitset, bitarray

The following is the implementation of BitSet in the solution of question 10-4 in cracking the coding interview book. Why is it allocating an array of size/32 not (size/32 + 1). Am I missing something here or this is a bug?

If I pass 33 to the constructor of BitSet then I will allocate only one int and If I try to set or get the bit 32, I will get an AV!

```
package Question10_4;

class BitSet {
    int[] bitset;

    public BitSet(int size) {
            bitset = new int[size >> 5]; // divide by 32
    }

    boolean get(int pos) {
            int wordNumber = (pos >> 5); // divide by 32
            int bitNumber = (pos & 0x1F); // mod 32
            return (bitset[wordNumber] & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;
    }

    void set(int pos) {
            int wordNumber = (pos >> 5); // divide by 32
            int bitNumber = (pos & 0x1F); // mod 32
            bitset[wordNumber] |= 1 << bitNumber;
    }
```

}

Comment: Alternatively we can allocate an array of ceil(size / 32.0) elements to avoid allocating an extra element when size is divisible by 32.

Comment: I can only assume that this was overlooked because it was only supposed to cover the case of 32,000 elements, i.e. a multiple of 32. For any number N that is not a multiple of 32, this code will - as you said - fail. You should drop the authors a note to let them know so they can fix that.

Comment: I checked the [Errata](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AuwEKO7o6mrAdFdhZHRlN1JUc3dEVFRNMDJzWlE1VXc&output=html) of that book, and the mistake is not listed. Considering they have corrections as recent as 5 days ago today, I would definitely write them an email; worst case scenario, you and I are wrong and they tell you why.

Comment: @GBach for any N less than 32,001 the code will not fail. The construction of the bitset in the solution in the book does not depend on N. The size of the bitset in the answer is set to 32,000 exactly to cover the scenario in the question, where N <= 32,000. Rather than a mistake, it is just a special case solution.

Comment: @groovy: Say he wants to manage values up to 31, which is 11111 in binary. 11111 >> 5 == 0, so the constructor call `BitSet(31)` will initialize an array of size 0, so it will not manage 31 numbers. `>> 5` divides by 32 and floors the result, which is not what it needs to do.

Comment: @G.Bach you are correct in your example. However, the OP asked "Why is it allocating an array of size/32." The OP posted only part of the solution he is referring to. That's exactly what I explained. This bitset is not designed to take any argument. It takes the argument in the other part of the solution that the OP did not post - a function called `checkDuplicates` that initializes the bitset with the parameter 32000 (which would handle N=31 just fine), in order to solve a very specific question. This is not a mistake, just a special implementation of a bitset to answer a specific question.

Comment: If this BitSet is custom designed for size 32000, they should have set the size in BitSet class itself rather than taking a variable size in its constructor. It looks to me like they were trying to have a generic implementation for the BitSet class but they have missed the case I mentioned. Anyway an email to the authors as G. Bach suggested would let us know if this is wrong or by design.

Comment: @groovy If it were designed to handle one specific situation, then the cleaner design would have been to not write a constructor that takes a parameter and fails for values of `size` that are not multiples of 32 and instead hardcode the size 32000 into the constructor. The way the constructor for the BitSet is written suggests that it works for any `size`, but it doesn't.

Comment: @G.Bach and Red, now I'm curious to hear the authors' response as well...maybe you could update the question when you receive it.

Comment: Sure, I have already filed a bug and will update the question as soon as they get back to me.

Comment: And finally I got a response :)

Thanks! I've updated this for the next printing.

...................................................................
Gayle Laakmann McDowell
Founder / CEO, CareerCup.com

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from reading the solution you mention (on page 205), and the little I understand about computer programming, it seems to me that this is a special implementation of a bitset, meant to take the argument of 32,000 in its construction (see the `checkDuplicates` function. The question is about examining an array with numbers from 1 to N, where N is at most 32,000, with only 4KB of memory).

This way, an array of 1000 elements is created, each one used for 32 bits in the bit set. You can see in the bitset class that to get a bit's position, we (floor) divide by 32 to get the array index, and then mod 32 to get the specific bit position.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, answer in the book is incorrect.
Correct answer:

```
bitset = new int[(size + 31) >> 5]; // divide by 32
```